# Hierarchial Linq to SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Let's say you have a database of products, these products are tied to a region. Each region has a parent -> child relationship. For example let's say you can buy a banana anywhere in the US, an apple anywhere in Minnesota, and an orange anywhere in Minneapolis.

If I was looking to get a list of products available for sale in Minneapolis(Banana, Apple, Orange) I might make a Linq query like this.

```
public static List<Product> GetProducts(int regionId)
{
    using (var db = new DataContext())
    {
        return (from p in db.Products
                where GetRegions(regionId).Contains(p.Region)
                select p).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

What I can't come up with is what GetRegions would look like, do I just make List an optional parameter and then do add to the collection recursively? Or is there something smarter(less manual) built into the Linq syntax that I'm unaware of?

**GetRegions**

```
// Pseudo code, untested. I feel like it should be easier.
private static List<Region> GetRegions(int regionId, List<Region> regions = null)
{
    if (regions == null)
        regions = new List<Region>();

    using (var db = new DataContext())
    {
        var data = (from r in db.Regions
                    where r.Id == regionId
                    select r).SingleOrDefault();

        if (data != null)
        {
            regions.Add(data);
            regions = GetRegions((int)data.ParentId, regions);
        }
    }

    return regions;
}
```

Comment: could you please add the code of `GetRegions` method?

Comment: @FelipeOriani I have added a possible implementation of GetRegions, I haven't run it through the compiler I'm not sure it works it's just a representation of the direction I was headed in and I'm questioning if there isn't something more natural that I have missed.

Comment: This is rather about LINQ to Entities and it's not possible to write recursive queries in LINQ to Entities. But it's possible to write a recursive query using `WITH ... AS (SELECT ...)` syntax, then execute it using the data context by calling the generic execute query method, which automatically fills a object with properties same as a record in the record (say `IEnumerable<MyClass>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the result of GetRegions() in regions and then do something like this

```
 List<Product> productsToDisplay = new List<Product>(); 

  regions.ForEach(t =>
      {
           productsToDisplay.AddRange(products.Where(u => u.RegionId == t.RegionId));
       }
  );
```

**OR**

```
productsToDisplay = (from product in products
                                join region in regions
                                on product.RegionId equals region.RegionId
                                select product).ToList<Product>();
```

Comment: I guess I'm not seeing the value? GetProducts seems pretty clean and does work, what I'm assuming can be done better is GetRegions?